# Where should we hold a SFSE Meetup at Dreamforce, and who wants to organise it?

Tags: discussion, dreamforce

### **See [SFSE DF18 Meetup Official Invite](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2789/102) for registering in Eventbrite to attend.**

---

Ok, so Elliot previously posted a question asking if we should have a meetup, and I think the resounding answer is **YES**, and I've secured some funding from Salesforce to put towards the cost.

Now the question is where should we hold it, and who would like to organise it. I think a few people (2-3) should likely be involved. I'm going to create a  wiki-answer below for people to organise a committee of sorts (first come first served?) and other answers should include potential venues. We've already had a potential offer from [@glls](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/users/31663/glls) which I'll include below too.

Comment: Can we get probable dates/timelines? It would help plan in advance.

Comment: Dates and Timelines would definitely help!

Comment: I won't be attending DF (again) this year :(

Comment: Everyone please register for [SFSE DF18 Meetup Invite](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/sfse-df18-meetup-invite)

Answer (score 13):

**Meetup Details**

https://www.eventbrite.com/e/sfse-meetup-at-dreamforce-2018-tickets-49769437728

The office for the meetup is near the embarcadero (1.5 miles away from Moscone Center)

[image]

**Food & Beverage Related:**

> - We will be ordering some snacks for the meetup
> - Possibility of Beer on Tap

**Date/Time & Address**

> **The Meetup will take place at: [620 Davis St, San Francisco, CA 94111, USA](https://www.google.com/maps/place/BelCham+(Belgian-American+Chamber+of+Commerce)/@37.7981567,-122.4005475,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x8085805e2d97c473:0x231d0bbeb06d445!8m2!3d37.7981567!4d-122.3983588)**
>
> **Thursday 27th - 6 PM to 9 PM**

For questions, suggestions, or anything related to the meetup, feel free to join:

> [Slack SFSE - DF2018](https://join.slack.com/t/sfse-df2018/shared_invite/enQtNDE0NzQzMTcwMTc5LTQzNGQ5NDEwNGVkMzdjMmVjMTY2NDY1ZWFiOTgxZmEyNjI5OWY2MDMyYzFlNDRiOTI1NDY1N2EyOGUyM2IyODY)

Comment: this made my day!

Comment: So this is all confirmed and we can promote it?

Answer (score 7):

**List of Attendees**

(*Please add your username to this list*):

- @glls
- [@codeyinthecloud](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/55478/rajesh-varma-mudunuri)
- [@David-Reed](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/46017/david-reed)
- @k..
- [@matt-lacey](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/users/78/matt-lacey)
- [@daniel-ballinger](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/users/102/daniel-ballinger)
- [@meighanrockssf](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/11653/meighanrockssf)
- [@pranay-jaiswal](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/19118/pranay-jaiswal)
- [@crmprogdev](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2212/crmprogdev)
- [@GrayJustise](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/users/138/kris-gray)
- [@ChristianSzandorKnapp](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/users/27272/christian-szandor-knapp)
- [@eliotharper](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5449/eliot-harper)
- [@daniel-hoechst](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/87/daniel-hoechst)
- [@adam-spriggs](https://stackexchange.com/users/429467/adam-spriggs)
- [@robert-sösemann](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/256/robert-s%C3%B6semann)
- [@christian-menzinger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/26940/christian-menzinger)
- [@gauravkheterpal](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/10881/gaurav-kheterpal)
- [@himanshu](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/17316/himanshu)

Comment: I think this has to be a Community wiki for other to be able to edit!

Comment: yup, you are right - Done

Comment: Is a online session planned too? ;) Would attend that one :)

Comment: We will most likely try to set one up

Comment: If the online session is planned, it would be nice if someone can share some information in that matter. (Link / Registration / ...)

Comment: I will check tomorrow at the office and update with a G2meeting link once I have it

Answer (score 5):

List of people who want to help Organise the event:

**Your name here!**

1. [@codeyinthecloud](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/55478/rajesh-varma-mudunuri)(I'm not SF native but would love to contribute my share to make this successful. I'm a DF Newbie!)
2. @glls =)
3. @gauravkheterpal - Happy to help in whatever ways I can!
4. @himanshu - Happy to help :)

Comment: If you would like to show up early to help, feel freee to do so (5:30ish)

Answer (score 4):

It was so cool to meet you all in person! Extra kudos to @glls and @codeyinthecloud for organizing everything.