# SFSE DF18 Meetup Official Invite

Tags: discussion, dreamforce

Hi everyone please make sure to register for this eventbrite invite to help us track the attendees and stay connected.
[SFSE Meetup at Dream Force 2018](https://www.eventbrite.com/e/sfse-meetup-at-dreamforce-2018-tickets-49769437728)

I apologise for the inconvenience but would love to see the attendees from [Where should we hold a SFSE Meetup at Dreamforce, and who wants to organise it?](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2765/where-should-we-hold-a-sfse-meetup-at-dreamforce-and-who-wants-to-organise-it)  register here. Thanks for your cooperation

> NOTE: Seating is limited